# Java Clearcase API

Tags: java, clearcase

Is there a Java ClearCase API?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update 2016 (as mentioned by [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4576324/hack)'s [answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29836395/6309))

I mentioned since 2010 the CM API multiple times, as [soon as 2012](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35358141/6309) and as recently as [last March 2016](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150287/6309).
Since ClearTeam 8.x, this API [does support dynamic view](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30161755/6309), as well as [snapshot views with 8.0.1.7](https://mediacenter.ibm.com/media/ClearCase+snapshot+view+support+in+ClearTeam+Explorer+and+CM+API/0_kw9wsrwa).

See more with [Rational ClearCase CM API introduction (v 9.0.0)](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.team_api.doc/topics/c_introduction.htm).
Its "[installation and setup requirements](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSH27_9.0.0/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.team_api.doc/topics/c_setup.htm)" do involve Java, with at least:

- Rational CM API component infrastructure JAR files
- Rational CM API subprovider JAR file for ClearCase®

---

Original answer (2010, pre ClearCase Team Explorer)

The is no Java API dedicated for ClearCase.

There is a **[Java CM API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?ratlid=cctocbody&rs=984&uid=swg21117682)**, but about the [Rational CM Server](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/09/clearcasecmserverperformanceimprovement/index.htmls) used by **CCRC** (a light-client installation, a simple web server which will forward all request to the actual ClearCase VOB server), not for ClearCase per se:

- it won't support dynamic views (since a CCRC always operates with snapshot "web" views)
- it won't support *all* ClearCase operations, only some of the ones supported by CCRC.

Comment: How does the CC plugin in eclipse work? Perhaps that can be used in a non-eclipse context?

Comment: @omerkudat: it encapsulates `cleartool` commands and direct call to ClearCase executable (like the `lsvtree`)

Comment: any development in this route since two years ago?  or still nothing?

Comment: @foampile the Java API is still reserved for the CM server (see http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v8r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.rational.clearcase.team_api.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_introduction.htm), and not support (with CC8.0) dynamic views: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474

Comment: Hi VonC, Will you please correct this answer to reflect the status noted below?  Thanks!

Comment: @hack Sure. I have updated this 6 years old answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

The (Java) CM API for ClearCase was originally only available for the ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC), which at the time (V7.1), only supported Web views.

In V8.0, the CM API was enhanced to support dynamic views:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474

In V8.0.1.6, the CM API was enhanced to support snapshot views:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21691355

In V8.0.1.7, a new type of view for CCRC, the "automatic view", was introduced and was immediately supported by the CM API:

- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27045000
- http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21699087

Thus, as of V8.0.1.6, the CM API supported all available types of views in ClearCase.