# how to create a webservice to wrap a perl scripts or shell scripts

Tags: web-services, perl, soa, webservice-client

Our development is mostly on windows, VCS is ClearCase. We also use quite lot of scripts (perl, bash) on Linux to do code quality checks, regression tests etc.  For example a script takes stream name, creates a dynamic view, generate a CPD report for the newly added files. Another one submits specific tests to a sun grid engine(SGE)

Currently user should login to a linux machine with a specific account, then edit some configuration files and run the scripts. User sometimes makes unwanted edits and creates trouble.

We could probably improve the flow by using rsh.

I guess exposing  the whole thing via web service may better. The user could then use a java program(web service client) to invoke the taks.

```
   java com.check.MyQualityChecks -stream blah -generate-cpd
```

Is there any thing that could help to me wrap existing scripts via a web-service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a direct `cleartool` encapsulation through web service.
The closest existing service is for `CCRC` (ClearCase Remote client), with its [Java CM API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775665/java-clearcase-api/3776095#3776095), which you could use if Linux machine was a `CCRC` server.

I would recommend developing your own web service, which would then call the script, but beware of the primary group and owner executing that script through the web service: the account needs to be in the right group (one of the groups of the Vob) and with the right umask (in order to create correctly protected views).

Comment: Thanks. I see a note saying CCRC does not support dynamic view. Using dynamic view is kind of necessary in our setup.

Comment: @Jayan: sure, CCRC is not adapted in your case. That is why encapsulating your script on the server side is much better.

Comment: Thank you.. Reached here http://search.cpan.org/~moconnor/REST-Application-0.992/lib/REST/Application.pm