# How to see eclipsed files on ClearTeam Explorer?

Tags: clearcase, clearcase-remote-client

I have an eclipsed file in my ClearCase dynamic view.

If I use ClearCase Explorer, I see it's eclipsed (the yellow moon icon).

If I check the command-line, I see it's eclipsed indeed.

When I use ClearTeam Explorer, it does not specify it's eclipsed (no text, icon or something like that). Since I tend to use the new explorer, I'm wondering how it should work on this situation?

Comment: I see you have accepted, but what version of ClearTeam client are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can depend on your ClearTeam version ([release notes for 8.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21504789)), since

> ### CM API support for dynamic views
>
> The ClearCase CM API now supports dynamic views. For detailed information on API changes, refer to [Technote 1566574](https://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474).

Other than that, not of the [ClearCase fixes](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27023148) reports any issue for eclipsed files.