# COM reference or Command tool for ClearTeam Explorer

Tags: clearcase, cleartool

I have been using IBM Rational ClearTeam Explorer version 8.0.0. I like to come up with customized tool(WPF application) to performing ClearTeam actions like makebaseline, checkin, checkout.

Is there any command tool and COM object availabe to perform these functions. I would be helpful if there are any reference link also.

Answer (score 0):

The official API for CM/ClearTeam is in java, not COM.

It is the [CM API](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21566474), a standards-based Java API for ClearCase, which in the 8.0 release, adds support for ClearCase dynamic views. It also adds partial support for UCM deliver and rebase operations, and ClearCase/Rational Team Concert work item integration.

You can use that java API with WebSphere Portlet Factory (WPF) to [develop a portlet application](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/websphere/tutorials/0606_coqueiro/).

Comment: Vonc, Thanks for the reply. WPF which i meant was Windows Presentation Foundation(windows application). Is there any DLLs(Dynamic Link Libraries) available for this API.

Comment: @Manojkumar not that I know of. This is full java.