# CM API allows to create a view in the wrong region(group) if the given stream is of different region

Tags: clearcase

I am looking for ways to check weather the selected pvob is under the group given, else the view should not be created.

Answer (score 1):

Simply try a `cleartool lsvob -region <yourRegion/Group>`.

See [`cleartool lsvob`](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSSH27_8.0.1/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.cc_ref.doc/topics/ct_lsvob.htm):

```
- reg/ion network-region
```

> Confines the VOB listing to include only the VOBs registered for one or more network regions. (The `mkvob` and `mktag` commands have a `-region` option, which can be used to assign VOB tags to specific network regions.)
> The `network-region` argument can include pattern-matching characters as described in the `wildcards_ccase` reference page.

So if `cleartool lsvob -reg aRegion YourPVobTag` does not return anything, that PVOBTag is not define in the specified region.

Comment: I am new to the cm-api plugin, i dint knew how to run the above command inside the plugin, with the help of above ibm reference pages i was able to get something working.

Comment: @user5722923 Let me check the doc I mentioned in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36150287/6309

Answer (score 1):

```
PropertyRequest wantedProps = new PropertyRequest(
CcRegistryRegion.VOB_TAG_LIST.nest(Resource.DISPLAY_NAME));
CcRegistryRegion region = provider.doGetDefaultCcRegistryRegion(wantedProps);
for (CcVobTag vobTag : region.getVobTagList()) {
    CCLogger.log(listener, vobTag.getDisplayName()+" ### VOB list");
}
```

after getting the provider object the following code can access the pvob under the region